# Inserting data in database MYSQL , data getting mixed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I have some troubles to insert data in the database , values get mixed between two rows. I did try to do an only while loop but even that doesn't work so i m gonna put my code as it was at the start . Any advices or solution are welcome , it will be great. Here is the echo that i get on the two insert query after puting test in textareas for commentaries boxes:

Choix refer to radio button values and Commentara to values of commentaries boxes (textarea).

```
INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES('test1','test1') 
INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES('test2','test2') 
INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES('test3','test3') 
INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES('test4','test4')
```

PS: I'm using Navicat for MYSQL and I'm still new on PHP so please take your time to explain.

Best Regards A.V.

```
   <?php
$link=Mysqli_connect($host,$login,$pass,$dbname);
$un = 0;
$kv = 0 ;
$msgerror = "Veuillez remplir tous les champs ";    

if(isset($_POST["bouton10"])){



    $id = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo4"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo4"] : "";
    $Nom = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo1"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo1"] : "";
    $Prenom = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo2"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo2"] : "";
    $Email = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo3"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo3"] : "";
    $RefClient = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo5"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo5"] : "";
    if ($id !="" && $Nom !="" && $Prenom !="" && $Email !="" && $RefClient !=""){

        $recherche= "SELECT Ref,Question,Choix,Commentara FROM questionnaire WHERE Qref ='$id'";


        mysqli_query($link,$recherche);





        $result= mysqli_query($link,$recherche);
        $num_results = $result->num_rows;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $Ref =$row["Ref"];
            $Question       =$row["Question"];

            $un++;
            $kv++;

            echo" <tr bgcolor=\"white\">

            <td>$Question  </td>
            <td>
                3<input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"3\">
                2<input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"2\">
                1<input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"1\">
                0<input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\"  value = \"0\">
                PA<input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"PA\">
            </td>
            <td width = \"60\"> <textarea name =\"$kv\" id =\"kv\" rows=\"5\" placeholder=\"Votre commentaire\"></textarea> </td> 
        </tr>


    </div>
</div>
"; 

}
}
else {

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msgerror')</script>";

}
}

$kv = 1;
$un = 1;
$i= 1 ;

if (isset($_POST["bouton11"]))   {





    while(isset($_POST[$un])||(isset($_POST[$kv]))){
        $choix = $_POST["$un"];
        $comment = $_POST["$kv"];


        $enregistrer = "INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara)  VALUES('$choix','$comment') ";

        $un++;
        $kv++;
        $i++;
        echo"$enregistrer";
        mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer); 

    }
//Besoin d'un correctif

    //while(isset($_POST[$kv])) {
    //  $comment = $_POST["$kv"];


    //  $enregistrer2 = "INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUES('$comment')";
       // $kv++;

     // echo"$enregistrer2";

    //  mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer2);
    //}

}



?>
```

Here is the form:

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
   <HTML>
      <HEAD>
         <TITLE>Foredeck_Testeur</TITLE>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="utf-8">
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
         <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer-distributed-with-address-and-phones.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tab.css">
         <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">

         <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tab.js"></script>


         <style type="text/css">
           .footer {
              min-width: 100%;
              height: auto;
              text-align: center;
              background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
              position: fixed;
              bottom: 0%;
              margin-top: 50%;
           }

           .wrapper {
              min-height: 100%;
              height: auto !important;
              height: 100%;
              margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
           }




        </STYLE>


     </HEAD>


     <BODY bgcolor="#6495ED">
      <form method ="post" id="">

         <table class="center-table" border ="1" align="center" >

            <tr bgcolor="#b0bffc">   
               <td>Nom:</TD><TD><input type="text" class="form-control" name ="Picolo1" id="Picolo1" > </textarea></td><td><P>(Obligatoire*)</P></td>  




            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#b0bffc">
               <td>Prénom:</TD><TD><input type="text" class="form-control" name ="Picolo2" id="Picolo2"> </textarea></td><td><P>(Obligatoire*)</P></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#b0bffc">
               <td>Email:</TD><TD><input type="mail" class="form-control" name ="Picolo3" id="Picolo3"> </textarea></td><td><P>(Obligatoire*)</P></td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#b0bffc">
               <td>Référence Questionnaire:</td>
               <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name ="Picolo4" id="Picolo4" > </textarea></td> <td> (Obligatoire*)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#b0bffc">
               <td>Référence Client:</td>
               <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name ="Picolo5" id="Picolo5" > </textarea></td> <td> (Obligatoire*)</td>
            </tr>
            <Tr>
               <TD bgcolor="#b0bffc">
                  <Center><button type="submit" name="bouton10" id="bouton10" class="btn btn-default" >Confirmer</button></Center>
               </TD>
            </TR>
         </table>
         <BR>

            <table class="center-table" border ="1" align="center"  >

               <tr bgcolor="#b0bffc">   <td> Question</td> <td>Choix</td> <td>Commentaires</td>   </tr>

               <?php
               include("bdconnect_Foredeck.php");
               include("foredeckaffiche_client.php");
               include("foredeck_insert_client.php");

               ?>

            </Table>
            <BR>


               <Center><button type="submit" name="bouton11" id="bouton11" class="btn btn-default" >Enregistrer</button></Center>
               <BR>
                <BR>
                 <Center>
                  <a href ="Foredeckmain.php" >Retour</button> </a> 


               </Center>
            </form>
         </div>
         <div class="footer">
           <p>
              <font color="white"> Foredeck Consulting Ltd &copy;  2017 </font>
           </p>
        </div>
     </BODY>
  </HTML>
```

Comment: how do you want it to be inserted?

Comment: Like that : one value according to which radio button selected of the radio button set  and then the commentary .

Comment: You must say what should you want to store in database

Comment: SQL to help of the table for you to understand :                                                                                                               DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `questionnaire`;
CREATE TABLE `questionnaire` (
  `Qref` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `Ref` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Question` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Choix` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Commentara` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_Client` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Ref`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: Did you mean you want to insert both radipbutton selected and commentary to the same row?

Comment: Yes , radio button value in column choix and textarea values in column commentara .

Comment: @A.V See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

It's ok i got it !

```
<?php
$link=Mysqli_connect($host,$login,$pass,$dbname);
$un = 0;
$kv = 0 ;
$msgerror = "Veuillez remplir tous les champs ";    

if(isset($_POST["bouton10"])){



    $id = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo4"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo4"] : "";
    $Nom = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo1"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo1"] : "";
    $Prenom = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo2"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo2"] : "";
    $Email = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo3"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo3"] : "";
    $RefClient = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo5"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo5"] : "";
    if ($id !="" && $Nom !="" && $Prenom !="" && $Email !="" && $RefClient !=""){

        $recherche= "SELECT Ref,Question,Choix,Commentara FROM questionnaire WHERE Qref ='$id'";


        mysqli_query($link,$recherche);





        $result= mysqli_query($link,$recherche);
        $num_results = $result->num_rows;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $Ref =$row["Ref"];
            $Question       =$row["Question"];

            $un++;
            $kv++;

            echo" <tr bgcolor=\"white\">

            <td>$Question  </td>
            <td>
                3<input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un1\" value = \"3\">
                2<input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un2\" value = \"2\">
                1<input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un3\" value = \"1\">
                0<input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un4\"  value = \"0\">
                PA<input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un5\" value = \"PA\">
            </td>
            <td width = \"60\"> <textarea name =\"text_$kv\" id =\"kv\" rows=\"5\" placeholder=\"Votre commentaire\"></textarea> </td> 
        </tr>


    </div>
</div>
"; 

}
}
else {

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msgerror')</script>";

}
}

$kv = 1;
$un = 1;
$i= 1 ;

if (isset($_POST["bouton11"]))   {






while((isset($_POST[$kv]))||(isset($_POST[$un]))){ 
$comment = $_POST["text_$kv"]; 
$choix=$_POST["$un"]; 

$enregistrer = "INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES('$choix','$comment') "; 
$kv++; 
$un++; 
echo "$comment"; 
$i++; 
echo"$choix"; 
echo"$enregistrer"; 
mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer); 

}
//Besoin d'un correctif

    //while(isset($_POST[$kv])) {
    //  $comment = $_POST["$kv"];


    //  $enregistrer2 = "INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUES('$comment')";
       // $kv++;

     // echo"$enregistrer2";

    //  mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer2);
    //}

}



?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to insert both `radiobutton` and `textarea` to the same row,this is how you should do. Both the fields should be inserted from a single insert query

```
 if (isset($_POST["bouton11"]))
{

 $choix = $_POST["$un"];
$comment = $_POST["$kv"];
$enregistrer = INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES($choix,$comment);
mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer); 

}
```

Comment: There is a problem it s only for one insert , i have a lot of question in my survey .

Comment: I will edit my post according to your answer take a loot please.

Comment: sure...il have a look

Comment: Ok sure , take a look at the echo of my query now , it s look like the query doesn t take the values of radio button anymore . I will edit my post and put the form in to .

Comment: @A.V Try `echo $choix;` before the insert to check whether the value is being assigned

Comment: test1     INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES('test1','test1')  test2 INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES('test2','test2')   test3INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES('test3','test3')     test4INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES('test4','test4')                           It's look like it's taking value from the Textarea  and not from the radio button ...

Comment: @A.V then how do you want it to come?

Comment: let say my table is like " Question // Choice // Commentary '',  for every question you have a radio button set and a textarea to put a commentary .  So the insert will be like getting radio button value of the selected radio button and the commentary that the custommer did write.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135554/discussion-between-affaz-and-a-v).